# jQueryFullPage.js: fadein elements when reach specific section

Tags: jquery, html, fullpage.js

I made a website using jQuery fullPage.js.

There are two fixed buttons, for the next and previous section, and what i'm tring to achive, is fadein previous button only when users moves into the second section.

The problem is, when i'm using the mousewheel, the button fadein, but the section doesn't move to the second one, and both buttons stop to work.

This is my jQuery code:

```
$('#fullpage').fullpage({
    onLeave: function(index, nextIndex, direction){
        //after leaving section 2
        if(index == '1' && nextIndex == '2' && direction =='down'){
            $('.tasto_indietro').fadeIn(500, function(){
                $(this).css({
                    'transition': 'all 0.2s linear 0s',
                    '-moz-transition': 'all 0.2s linear 0s',
                    '-webkit-transition': 'all 0.2s linear 0s',
                    '-o-transition': 'all 0.2s linear 0s'
                });
            });
        }
    }
});
```

HTML structure is like this

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="section schermata_home" id="section0">
        </div>
        <div class="section schermata_web" id="section1">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Anyone have some ideas?

Comment: Can you reproduce it in this fiddle? http://jsfiddle.net/97tbk/148/
Also, check the javascript console and post in your question what you get in there.

Comment: Also, where is yoiur `.tasto_indietro` element placed? I can not see it in your html mark-up.

Comment: And... you should initialize the plugin with `$('.container').fullpage...` I don't see the element `#fullPage` in your code either.

Comment: It works perfect in the fieddle, but not in my site.. Probably there's something in cinflict with other script
http://jsfiddle.net/97tbk/202/

Comment: Then the problem is on your site. Not in fullpage.js. And... you didnt add the content of your javascript console yet... (your updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/97tbk/204/)